# How to get the end the time of the current jenkins build in pipeline code?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My requirement is to get the end time of the current build in pipeline code.
How to get it?

Comment: At what point you want it? When the build is still building?

Answer (score 1):

You can take `currentBuild.startTimeInMillis + currentBuild.duration` at the end of the build:

```
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
...
def endTime = currentBuild.startTimeInMillis + currentBuild.duration
def endTimeString = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(endTime))
println endTimeString
```